# TSQLT Database Unit test

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, tsqlt

I am trying to hands on with TSQLT unittest framework for first time and have come across a problem. I have a stored proc like this which returns some numbers

```
Use Mydatabase
Declare @parameter1, @parameter2,@paramter3

BEGIN
SELECT @parameter1 = dbo.[function](@paramter2,parameter3)
..
..

-- Now some Dynamic SQL joins on two tables
BEGIN
SET @SQL = 'SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM  FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.COLUMN1 = 
            TABLE2.COLUMN2 WHERE TABLE2.COLUMN3 = + CAST(@parameter1 as varchar(10))
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, Output parameter
return
```

The problem is the table1 and table2 are updated daily and I can't assert to values that are changing so I came across fake tables and spy procedures,

1. Is there a way to utilize the spyprocedures to use the faketables rather than original tables.?
2. Since my actual db and Unit test db are different but with in same connection, how can I reference the actual to the test one as I am getting error as

   Cannot use SpyProcedure on [WD0000\server].[database].[dbo].[usp.mystoredproc] because the procedure does not exist

TSQLT code

```
    EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass 'SegmentSizeTest'
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE SegmentSizeTest.[test that checks the segment size]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return_value int,@TotalCount int,@OneCount int,@TwoCount int
    declare @Criteria Varchar(MAX)
    declare @rampUpFactor int
    declare @expected int
    declare @actual int


SET @Criteria = 'My Criteria'
SET @GeoflexCriteria = NULL
 --@TotalCount = @TotalCount OUTPUT
 --@OneCount = @OneCount OUTPUT
    --  @TwoCount = @TwoCount OUTPUT
SET @rampUpFactor = 1
set @expected = 160486

------Fake Table
    EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable 'UnitTest.Household';
    EXEC tSQLT.FakeTable 'UnitTest.Customer';
--
..Insert to UnitTest.Household and UnitTest.Customer tables

------Execution

EXEC    @return_value = [VAReportingDB].[dbo].[GetSegmentSize] 
        @Criteria = @Criteria,
        @TotalCount = @TotalCount OUTPUT,
        @OneCount = @OneCount OUTPUT,
        @TwoCount = @TwoCount OUTPUT

SELECT  @TotalCount as N'@TotalCount',
        @OneCount as N'@OneCount',
        @TwoCount as N'@TwoCount'

------Assertion
    EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals @expected, @TotalCount;
END;
GO
```

Comment: Rather than running unit tests against unknown data, the general tsqlt approach I suggest is 1) create fake tables, 2) insert known unit test data into fake tables, 3) run the proc using the fake tables, 4) assert equals. You need to install the tsqlt framework in all databases under test.

Comment: thanks but for this instance my procs are using dynamic sql against fixed tables so how can I run this sp against fake tables

Comment: Both static and dynamic SQL can use fake tables. It might help if you post your tsql code.

Comment: sorry but a looklike example is in question already

Comment: But I don't see any tsqlt code in your question.

Comment: added in the question

Answer (score 0):

FakeTable replaces the original table wit a test double. Therefore any code that is written to access the original table, dynamically or otherwise, will “see” the faked table during a test.

Independently, you should pass in @parameter1 to sp_executesql instead of concatenating it into your Sql statement. At least if your original code is similar to what you posted here.

Comment: I've added an example of my TSQLT tests, now when I call the testable SP to get the actual result it is taking values from the dynamic sql in SP now even if I create fake table how will I make sure that my SP will fetch results from fake table